# Image is not showing up in react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

i have the following Code and for some reason the Logo isn't showing up and i cant figure out why is so. The image is in the folder src -> pages -> images.

```
  import dress from "./images/dress.png"

  const I1 = () => {
  return (
  <div class="text-center m-10 mx-96">

    <img src= {<dress />} alt="logo"/>
    
    <div class="mt-10 mx-60">
        <div class="flex flex-row gap-5">
            <div>
            <img   ....
```

Comment: It should be `src= {dress}` not`src= {<dress />}`.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an image, `src` attribute value should be `dress`:

```js
import dress from "./images/dress.png"

  const I1 = () => {
  return (
  <div class="text-center m-10 mx-96">

    <img src={dress} alt="logo"/>
    
    <div class="mt-10 mx-60">
        <div class="flex flex-row gap-5">
            <div>
            <img   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use image tag like this :

```html
<img src={dress} alt="logo"/>
```

in your code "dress" is not component it's path for image that you are import on top of the code.